# Javascript replace console.log() with Alert () method

Tags: javascript

I want to replace the console.log output with a windows alert displaying all persons data.

```js
class person {
  constructor(name, job, color, age, licExpiryDate) {
    this.personsname = name;
    this.jobtitle = job;
    this.haircolor = color;
    this.personsage = age;
    this.licenseExpiryDate = licExpiryDate;
  }
}
let person1 = new person('David Smith', 'Marketing Manager', 'Brown', 25, '2020-06-01');
console.log(person1);
```

Tried replacing console.log with alert( person1 ) ; but did not work.

Comment: "did not work"; did anything happen? error in the console? I think `alert()` requires a string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`alert()` converts its argument to a string, and objects by default convert to just `[object Object]`.

To get a string that actually shows the contents of the object, use `JSON.stringify()`.

```js
class person {
  constructor(name, job, color, age, licExpiryDate) {
    this.personsname = name;
    this.jobtitle = job;
    this.haircolor = color;
    this.personsage = age;
    this.licenseExpiryDate = licExpiryDate;
  }
}
let person1 = new person('David Smith', 'Marketing Manager', 'Brown', 25, '2020-06-01');
alert(JSON.stringify(person1, null, 4));
```

Answer (score 0):

Try `alert(JSON.stringify(person1))`